# Is it okay to use large nested Data Structures in Java using Lists and Maps?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, data-structures, out-of-memory

I am currently working in a project where I need to use grouping concepts. Hence I need to use a large Map like this.

```
Map< String,List< Map < String,List< Map< String,List< String>>>>>> objLargeMap;
```

So My question is, Is it okay to use large nested datastructures like this. Will I get any issues like memory full exception or some other issues?

I have analysed other alternatives. But none of them seems to be working.  Please help me understand. It is also tricky to get data from the object. So far it is running fine. But I am afraid that there may be some trouble when it comes to production.

Comment: I think your code will be hard to read and ugly, but I don't forsee any out of memory errors assuming you have enough memory allocated to the JVM.  Maybe you could include the alternatives in your question?

Comment: `I have analysed other alternatives` ?

Comment: I'll be a bit more upfront than Tim and say: "NO - DON'T DO IT!". Java is an Object Oriented language, and as such you should create Objects (nested - if needed) and use them. the memory allocation cost is negligible and the reward for making the code (way) more readable and easier to maintain is priceless!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to improve readability etc, you should define beans wherever possible. So your expression could be:

```
Map< String,List<A>> objLargeMap; 

class A{
 Map < String,List<B>>
 //getters setters
}

class B {
 Map< String,List< String>>
 //getters setters
}
```

You will not have memory issues as long as you have enough heap to hold all objects.

Comment: This approach will certainly make the code slower Yet, this is perhaps the right way to go. Unreadable code is more dangerous than slow code :)

Comment: Yeah, readable code, good variable and method names, small classes... all of that is a must for a good long-term code :D